# If $f$ is uniformly continuous, converges to $0$ at $\pm\infty$, is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2 < \infty$?

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

Is it true that if $f$ is uniformly continuous and converges to $0$ at $\pm\infty$, that the improper integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f^2 < \infty$$
is finite?

I am currently reading a probability theory proof that seems to take this for granted, but it is not obvious to me. How can this be argued?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. Consider the function

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{-x}} & x\leq -1 \\
      -\frac{1}{4}x^2+\frac{5}{4} & -1< x< 1 \\
      \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} & x\geq 1
   \end{cases}$$

This function is differentiable for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and converges to $0$ at $\pm \infty$. The derivative is

$$f'(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{2(-x)^{3/2}} & x\leq -1 \\
      -\frac{1}{2}x& -1< x< 1 \\
      -\frac{1}{2 x^{3/2}} & x\geq 1
   \end{cases}$$

It is easy to see that this is continuous for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Further, we see that $|f'(x)|\leq \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $f(x)$ is [Lipschitz Contiuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Properties) (see the first property in the link). Thus, $f(x)$ is uniformly continuous over the real numbers. However,

$$\int_1^\infty f(x)^2dx=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx=\infty$$

Thus, the integral does not converge.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not true.  Every continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f \to 0$ at $\pm \infty$ is uniformly continuous.  Try e.g. $f(x) = 1/(1+\sqrt{|x|})$.